# how to use a max or ceiling in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a paginator that shows the following for page 1

records 1 through 10

10 being the number of records per page. Thing is for new users they might have under 10 records so showing 10 as the # per page doesn't work

How can I do something like this

```
if total_record_count is < 10, show total_record_count ELSE show 10 (records per page)
```

Thanks

Comment: Not trying to be pesky here, you are developing in rails/merb right? Have you looked at will_paginate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there's always [`Enumerable#min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001503):

```
<%= [posts.count, 10].min %>
```

Comment: For your particular case will be: